# TinyMCE - jQuery Plugin, setting a default Theme/Options Globally

Tags: jquery, tinymce, customization

I'm using `TinyMCE` for all my pages that require a WYSISYG.  And frankly, I have many.

I'm literally using the same code for instantiating the tinymce() jquery plugin for each page, and I'm wondering if there's a way to set my preferred options once, somewhere that each page already references, so I don't have to keep the same bulky code in each page.

Here's what I've done with each page so far:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("textarea#comments").tinymce({
    script_url : '/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', // Location of TinyMCE script 
    // General options 
    theme : "advanced", 
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist", 
    force_p_newlines : false, 
    force_br_newlines : true, 
    /*forced_root_block : '',*/ 
    // Theme options 
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,hr,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect|styleprops,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,removeformat,code,|,preview", 
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "", 
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "", 
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "", 
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top", 
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left", 
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom", 
    theme_advanced_resizing : true, 
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false 
});

});
</script>
```

I'd like to see simply this:

```
$("textarea#comments").tinymce();
```

From what I understand, `tinymce` comes with 2 themes: advanced & simple.  Advanced has too many options, while simple doesn't have enough.  So now I have to cherry-pick my options, but 
restating the code above on every page seems like madness.

any ideas?

Comment: Do you need the same custom theme on each page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addionally to Sébastien Gicquels answer you may have a default tinymce init object which you load using a script file

```
var init_base_object = {
    theme: 'advanced',
    language : 'en',
    ...
};

var tinymce_additional = {

    language : 'en',

    width: "800",
    height: "600",

        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : ""
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    init_obj = {element_id:'xyz', window: window};
    $.extend(true, tinymce_additional, init_base_object);
    $.extend(true, init_obj , tinymce_additional);
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddFrameControl',false, init_obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization code must be placed within HEAD element of all your pages which need tinyMCE.

In the official documentation, we can see :

> As an alternative, the tinyMCE.init statement can be put in it's own
>   file and referenced in a script tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/basic_config.js"></script>
</head>
```

source : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

So you can have one single file of configuration and call it in the head of your pages with only one line of code.